# Where should I place my questions on which there may be multi-religious answers?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question that requires answers from multiple religions. Where do I ask it? There should be a place for inter-religious dialogue. BTW I have read this: [Why not have religion.stackexchange.com instead of Christianity/Judaism/Biblical Hermeneutics?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111659/why-not-have-religion-stackexchange-com-instead-of-christianity-judaism-biblical)

Comment: Kindly add why you are downvoting this question

Comment: Well, if you read that question, what did you think about it? How does it relate? Just dropping a related link in your question doesn't give much context.

Comment: Best bet would be philosophy stackexchange.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, my question is _where do I ask it?_ Dropping the link implies that there is possibly no explicit answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can't ask a question about all religions in one place, and the answers in the question you linked explain why such a site isn't practical.  You can, however, *tailor* your question for each community whose input you want, and ask it there.  (Don't just cross-post the same question; that tends to produce poor quality and is discouraged.)

On each site ask your question from the perspective of *that religion*.  You'll then have to synthesize the results, same as for any project that requires answers from multiple communities (or multiple questions in the same community).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong ... _On each site ask your question from the perspective of that religion_ would practically (at least in some cases) mean overriding the _Don't just cross-post the same question_.

Comment: It wouldn't be the same question, it would be a series of similar questions: "Does Shia Islam teach A?" "Does the Catholic Church teach A?" and so on.

Comment: Or "what does (group) teach about X?" or "according to (group) how do you (achieve some outcome, e.g. gain salvation)?".  (Beware of "too broad", of course.)

Answer (score 4):

If a question has several "right" answers, it's probably not a good fit to the Stack Exchange model generally.

If, however, what you're after is a philosophical insight into, say, the similarities and/or differences between particular religions on a particular issue, then [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com) *might* be the place.

Here's what you [can ask about there](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and [what you can't](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)